# why the output is not good in some cases?

Tags: python

i feel stupid and don't know why the output is not good in some cases.
here is the output (at the end)
it sould find the first sub string in given string for example:
sim('banan','na') -> 'na'

```
 def rev (str):
    rev_str=''
    i =  len(str)-1;
    while (i >= 0):
        rev_str += str[i];
        i = i-1;
  return rev_str;
  ######################################
 def sim (str,sub):
   sub_len = len (sub);
   start = str.index(sub);
   rev_str = rev(str)
   rev_sub = rev(sub)

if (start ==0):
    start =1;

end = start + rev_str.index(rev_sub,start-1);

ret_val = ''
print start , end
for n in range (start,end):
    ret_val += str[n];

return ret_val;

            print sim('abcdef', 'abc')
            print sim('abcdef', 'bc')
            print sim('banana', 'na')

the output : 
        1 4
        bcd
        1 4
        bcd
        2 4
        na
```

Comment: It's unclear what output you want or why you want it...

Comment: i want to find the first occurance of sub string in the bigger stirng, for example sim('banana','na') will output the 'na'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sim(haystack, needle):
    if needle in haystack:
        return needle
```

If you want indices:

```
def sim(haystack, needle):
    index = haystack.index(needle) # throws ValueError when not found
    return (index, index + len(needle))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cat's solution. FWIW, you probably want to study a bit about slice syntax. If you're doing string manipulation, slices are a basic tool. I don't see from your code why you wanted to reverse your string, but if you must, try this:

```
my_string = "abcdefg"
reversed = my_string[::-1] # here's the slice magic
print(reversed)
```